# How to enable spell check in Adobe Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I have a long, text-heavy brochure created in Adobe Illustrator CS6. I don't want to copy the whole text to a Word document to run a spell check. Is there any way to run a spell check without leaving Illustrator? It would save me a day or so. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Asking here was easier than typing it into Google and [finding the official documentation on top](http://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/spelling-language-dictionaries.html)?

Comment: Previously, I was led to Stackexchange pages so I thought it would be better if I ask the question there.

Answer (score 8):

For spell-check in Illustrator cs6

Choose Edit > Check Spelling.

Click Start to begin checking the spelling.

When Illustrator displays misspelled words or other possible errors, do one of the following:

1. Click Ignore or Ignore All to continue spell-checking without changing a certain word.
2. Select a word from the Suggestions list or type the correct word in the top box, and then click Change to change.
3. Click Add to have Illustrator store the new word.

click Done when finish